# what to do when my wifi driver is not listed in drivers .i m using hp bs- series laptop with ubuntu 16.04,my wifi driver is realtak RTL8111

Tags: drivers, wireless

[driver is not listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIQBo.png)
wifi hardware is not listed`esudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for aju: 
  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: ac:e2:d3:d1:9b:d1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.22.8.116 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff`

Comment: @Rinzwind You're looking at the wrong network port. You quote the ethernet driver. OP has a problem with the wireless port.

Comment: Try booting the Ubuntu Live DVD 18.04 and look to see if it finds your wireless.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.